# Gproc how to get the process id of a registered process?

Tags: erlang

How can I get the process id of a registered process using gproc:-

I registered a process using

`gproc:reg({p,l,myroom})`

Now, I am using erlang:start_timer which expects either the Process Id or Registered name.

```
erlang:start_timer(3000, self(), "Test Msg"),
```

So, instead of self() I want to provide the Process id of myroom. So that all the users can get Test message after 3000 milliseconds.

Comment: Gproc documentation moved here: http://blog.rusty.io/2009/09/16/g-proc-erlang-global-process-registry/

Comment: The documentation is actually on GitHub: https://github.com/uwiger/gproc/blob/master/doc/gproc.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're probably trying to do the wrong thing here. `erlang:start_timer/3` takes a single pid as an argument, but you want to send a message to zero or more pids that have a local myroom property. It sounds like you may be better off using [gproc_ps](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc/blob/master/doc/gproc_ps.md) to send your message, and maybe just use

```
timer:apply_after(3000, gproc_ps, publish, [l, myroom, "Test Msg"]).
```

This will send the message to all pids that are subscribed to the myroom event at the time you're trying to send the message. This means that even Pids that subscribed *after* this was scheduled (but before it fires) will still receive the notification. This is probably the desired behavior. If not, you could do leave your registration as-is and just create a timer for each pid that has the myroom property:

```
[erlang:start_timer(3000, Pid, {msg, "Test Msg"}) || Pid <- gproc:lookup_pids({p, l, myroom})].
```

Answer (score 0):

Try gproc:lookup_pid({p, 1, myroom}).

Comment: Thanks for reply Jan, However, it generates an exception... ` exception error: bad argument
     in function  gproc:where/1
        called as gproc:where({p,l,jaan})
     in call from gproc:lookup_pid/1 (src/gproc.erl, line 1308)
`

Comment: Interestingly, It's gproc:lookup_pids({p,l,myroom}) which returns the process id, However, if I pass the same Pid to erlang:start_timer(3000, gproc:lookup_pids({p,l,myroom}), "Test Mg"). It generates a bad argument exception.. :(

Comment: After digging more into details. Even if I do that it will give me lists of the Pid which are registered under myroom but I want the Pid of the process myroom